# get the position of a descendant node from ancestor, not necessarily a sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

In the following xml snippet I have a section with a footnote, and a subsection with a footnote. I want to renumber the footnotes sequentially starting at the paper/section level, despite the fact that the fn's are not siblings

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<paper>
    <section>
        <title>My Main Section</title>
        <para>My para with a <footnote num="1">text</footnote> footnote.</para>
        <section>
            <title>my subsection</title>
            <para>more text with another <footnote num="1">more fn text.</footnote> footnote.</para>
        </section>
    </section>
</paper>
```

the expected output would be:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<paper>
<section><title>My Main Section</title>
    <para>My para with a <footnote num="1">text</footnote> footnote.</para>
    <section><title>my subsection</title>
    <para>more text with another <footnote num="2">more fn text.</footnote>     footnote.</para>
    </section>
</section>
</paper>
```

I was trying various things with xsl:number, but couldn't get anything to work. The closest I could get was the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="footnote/@num">
    <xsl:attribute name="num"><xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::paper/section//footnote)"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that gives the correct count of 2, but I'm not sure how to indicate that "I am the first of two footnotes in this main section".

I also tried writing a named template like so:

```
<xsl:template match="/paper/section">
    <section>
        <xsl:call-template name="renumberFNs"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </section>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="renumberFNs">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//footnote/@num">
        <xsl:attribute name="num"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

but that put the @num on the section. Any ideas?

Comment: "*renumber the footnotes starting at the paper/section level, so the fn's are not siblings*" I am not sure what that means. Why don't you post the expected result of the transformation?

Comment: added expected output, and edit for clarity (i hope :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
<xsl:template match="footnote/@num">
    <xsl:attribute name="num">
        <xsl:number count="footnote" level="any" from="paper/section"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: perfect, thanks. Miffed at myself for not picking that up from the docs I searched