# get nth descendant node of given typefrom context node, they may not be siblings

Tags: xslt, xpath

This is related to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372876/get-the-position-of-a-descendant-node-from-ancestor-not-necessarily-a-sibling) I asked awhile ago. Given this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<paper>
<section><title>My Main Section</title>
    <para>My para with a <footnote num="a">text</footnote> footnote.</para>
    <section><title>my subsection</title>
    <para>more text with another <empty/><footnote num="b">more fn text.    </footnote> footnote.</para>
    </section>
</section>
</paper>
```

I want an xpath, from the /paper/section node that will give me just the first footnote (@num="a")

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="/paper/section">
    <section>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//footnote[1]"/>
    </section>
</xsl:template>
```

but that returns both fn's. I assume because each fn is the first footnote node in its respective parent.

I tried a few variations:

```
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//footnote[position() = 1 ]"/>
```

that will return a footnote that is the first child of its parent, or the same as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372876/get-the-position-of-a-descendant-node-from-ancestor-not-necessarily-a-sibling)? The testing I did indicated they were the same.

I also tried a for-each loop, but wasn't able to pick anything up...

any ideas?
bp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried something along the lines of:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="/paper/section">
>     <section>
>         <xsl:apply-templates select="//footnote[1]"/>
>     </section>
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> but that returns both fn's.

This is a FAQ. See for example **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element/4008925#4008925)**.

**The XPath `[]` operator binds more strongly (has higher priority) than the `//` pseudo-operator**.

This is why,

```
//x[1]
```

selects all `x` elements in the document, that are the first `x` child of their parent.

In XPath, as in math, to override the default priority of operators, one uses parentheses.

**Use**:

```
(//x)[1]
```

**In this particular case**, substituting `x` with the specific element name, gives us this expression:

```
(//footnote)[1]
```

And in case the first `footnote` element in a particular sub-tree of the document is wanted, use:

```
 (.//footnote)[1]
```

where the context (current) node for the evaluation of the expression is the root of the sub-tree

---

**Explanation**:

`//` isn't actually an XPath operator -- it is just a shorthand. To quote the [**W3C XPath 1.0 specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

> // is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/

**This means that**:

```
//x[1]
```

**is expanded to**:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/x[1]
```

And this selects any `x` element that is the first `x` child of any node that is a descendant of the root (document) node.

**Do note** that the above expression is *very different* from:

`/descendant::x[1]`

and thus, the selected node-sets by the two expressions are generally different.

Comment: And you would need to add a leading dot if you want the first footnote _in this section_ as opposed to the first footnote _in the whole document_: `select="(.//footnote)[1]"` (the example in the question only has one section but the wording "I want an xpath, from the /paper/section node" suggests the real case has several)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
select="//footnote[1]"
```

try:

```
select="descendant::footnote[1]"
```

I will explain in a moment.

---

Actually, I don't have a good explanation; I can only quote from the [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

> **NOTE**: The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first
>   descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para`
>   elements that are the first para children of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

Using `descendant::para[x]` still would give me all the items of Index `x` until the end of the tree (**using it on Ranorex 8.1.2**).

But by applying `descendant::para[x][n]` I get exactly the Nth element going down the Tree of Index `X`, or even better using `descendant::para[][n]` to just get the first Nth element to be found going through all children and their children.